# Soup.find_all returns nothing yet the div and class are correct

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the job posts for position and location, lets say data analyst in North Carolina.
I have done the code before using requests and BeautifulSoup and it worked. Now i try the same thing but for some reason the find_all is not returning the div of that class although i still see it when i inspect the page.

My code goes something like this:

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import csv 
 
 response=requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data Scientist&l=South Carolina')
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
 cards=soup.find_all ('div',{'class':'job_seen_beacon'})
```

Then i try Len(cards) and it is supposed to turn a number 15, but it turns 0

Any ideas?

Comment: I ran it and in the response text there is no class named "job_seen_beacon". Are you sure you don't need JS enabled ?

Comment: How do i enable JS? i'm not sure about that. the class name is there when i inspect the page and when i tried this a month ago it worked. not sure what changed

Comment: Check your response you may run into cloudfare protection.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the request you send doesn't contain the class you need. Therefore I suggest switching to selenium for this case. You can still use beautifulsoup to parse and find the information you need. Therefore, try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'downloads',"chromedriver.exe")) #Replace with path to chromedriver
driver.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data Scientist&l=South Carolina')
raw = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw,"html.parser")
cards=soup.find_all ('div',{'class':'job_seen_beacon'})
```

This is now returning 15 elements:

```
print(len(cards))
```

Output:

```
15
```